# Why do some spells have a duration of 1 year, and others have a duration of a year and a day?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

The spell *Geas*, in a level 8 slot, has a duration of one year. The spell *Mass Suggestion*, in a level 9 slot, has a duration of a year and a day.

I'm already familiar with the [historical roots](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AYearAndADay) of the "year and a day" timeframe, but I'm curious about why some spells have that duration and others just have a 1 year duration.

Is there any statement **from the designers** about why this discrepancy exists? Speculation is **not** an acceptable answer.

Comment: Since the question and the one existing answer don't match, and yet the answer has been accepted, I am persuaded that the question is not clear enough to remain open for new answers. Please clarify what you're asking; perhaps explaining how the existing answer solves your problem could help clarify what problem the question is supposed to be describing.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I was asking for the reason of the difference between spells, purely out of interest. The answer I selected was chosen, because it explained it is most likely a lack of consistency. The extra explanation given about fantasy also is very helpful, because is was unaware about this before this question.

Comment: To add to my previous comment, i'm new to this site, and don't really get what you are asking, the answer below has answered my question completely. My belief was to accept is, because it resolved my question, did I overlook something?

Comment: If you look at the question right now, it asks for what designers have said is the reason, and says that the background on "a year and a day" is already known and unnecessary to explain. But the answer does not provide designer statements, and spends lots of space on background. The answer is the opposite of what the question is asking. Yet it's been accepted as answering the question, which it doesn't. So something about the question is confused or has gone wrong, hence it has been closed until the confusion is eliminated.

Comment: thank you for explaining, I didn't completely understand when a question was fully answered, correct answer was removed.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand; no answer has been removed.

Comment: I now realize that the answer is a good answer, but not correct. Probably the only correct answer is a reply or comment from a writer, but im leaving finding the answer up to the community

Answer (score 16):

### Legacy from previous editions and roots on fairy tales

[A Year and a Day](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AYearAndADay) is a common *trope* on fairy tales and stories about witches.

> The time span of a year and a day has many situations — legal and magical — where it is significant. For one thing, it sounds impressive, being more sonorous than merely a year. For another, it's been used in Real Life. For a third, it makes it clear that the **time is precise**; "a year" is sometimes used to mean approximately a year, but a year and a day makes it clear that the exact time is indicated.

A lunar year (13 lunar months of 28 days) plus a day is a solar year (365 days).  Also, 366 days would be a full year even if a [leap day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/February_29) was included.

It is also a [term adopted by common laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_and_a_day_rule) for this exact reason.

### Why some spells have a duration of a year?

*Geas* spell description should also have said *"a year and a day"* if they were written by the same designer who wrote *Mass Suggestion*. Or maybe it was simply a memory lapse of the designer.

We simply have a small problem of **lack of consistency**.

This is the kind of issues that *editors* should look up for and fix. In previous editions, we have seen spells being referenced as having "24 hours" durations aswell as "1 day" durations. 5th edition did a much better job at fixing those inconsistencies, but some of them (like the one you found) are still here and there. They should be reported so they can be fixed on future printings of the book.

For instance, this same issue does not happen with the spell *Planar Binding*:

> At Higher Levels: When you cast this spell using a spell slot of a higher level, the Duration increases to 10 days with a 6th-level slot, to 30 days with a 7th-level slot, to 180 days with an 8th-level slot, and to **a year and a day with a 9th-level spell slot**.

For all purposes, "*a year*" and "*a year and one day*" should be the same.

Comment: But strangely the OP has accepted this answer.  I'm going to decline the flags on this answer as a result, but it does indicate the OP is confused or miscommunicating.

Comment: @mxyzplk this answer has been edited since (3 hours ago) the OP last edit on his question (4 hours ago).

Comment: Not much of an edit though. The answer is still focused on things that *seem* to be irrelevant to the current form of the question, and was still accepted pre-edit based on those seemingly-unrelated parts. I am persuaded that there is a miscommunication going on, and have closed the question as unclear.

Comment: Fun Fact: If your campaign world has a year less than 179 days, casting Planar Binding at lvl 9 has a shorter duration than lvl 8